# Perforce: How to list overriden files that were not checked out?

Tags: perforce, p4v

There are cases when I override a file manually or automatically but didn't check out it in advance so that in p4v I see it as blue icon without red bird. Such file is not shown in pending list and I need to seek it in workspace tree.

How to filter out overriden but not checked out files in p4v?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the folder tree, select the folder that contains the files you modified outside of Perforce, then click `Actions->Reconcile Offline Work...` a dialog will appear that includes a list labeled "Modified files".  This is the list of files that were modified, but not checked out.  You will then have the option to check them out by selecting them and clicking the `Reconcile` button.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to reset these files without checking them out ?